# Xstream does not maintain order of child elements while unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, xstream

How maintain the order of unmarshalled child objects in a Set. Below is my xml, when converting to java objects order that I get in set is not A,B,C. How can I achieve that?

```
<company id="abc">
  <emp name="A"/>
  <emp name="B"/>
  <emp name="C"/>
</company>
```

**Edit:
Observations:**

1. In my Company.class I had defined `Set<Employee>` and when xstream unmarshall it, it create the set as HashMap, so the order is not maintained. 
   **Ques)** *How can I use LinkedHashMap in xstream to maintain the order?*
2. Then I defined the employee set as `LinkedHashSet<Employee>`. Doing this xstream create set as LinkedHashMap and order is maintained but Hibernate throws exception because there I have defined Set `<set name="employees">` and it throws error on casting Set to LinkedHashSet

> ```
> public void setEmployees(Set<Employee> emps){
>   this.packages = (LinkedHashSet<Employee>)emps;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using my custom Converter but I guess there has to be a better way that to used custom converter for such a small problem. I'll keep looking but until then.

Add this

```
xstream.registerConverter(new CompanyConverter());

public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader,UnmarshallingContext context) {

        Company comp = new Company();


        Set<Employee> packages = new LinkedHashSet<Employee>();

        while(reader.hasMoreChildren()){
            reader.moveDown();
            if("emp".equals(reader.getNodeName())){
                Employee emp = (Employee)context.convertAnother(comp, Employee.class);
                employees.add(emp);
            }
            reader.moveUp();
        }
        comp.setEmployees(employees);
        return comp;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Set  is not ordered.   If you like deifnite order,  use list.   This has nothing with xstream.

Comment: Certail Set implementations are ordered. Moreover he seems to be looking for ordering based on the data and not the order based on the occurence

Comment: as he is complaining about unmarshalling, he definitely  likes to have  order of occurence.  I'm guessing M%)

Comment: yes, I need order of occurrence but emp is implemented as Set in a company (Set<Emp> emps) because they have to be unique. So I cannot keep it as List either.

Comment: Set does not maintain any particular order.  It is contract....  If your API uses Set, then order does not matter.

Comment: SortedSet, a subclass of Set, has existed for as long as Set itself (since 1.2), so a more correct observation is that Set has nothing to say about whether an ordering exists or not.

Comment: This means if you got set from somewhere,  assume it is not ordered.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for ordering based on the content and not the order in which the emp element occurs in the XML instance. If this is the case then SortedSet can maintain natural ordering. But not sure how xstream unmarshalls it though. If there is a way to map it to SortedSet then you achieve what you are looking for.

If you want the data ordered by their occurence in XML instance then you could ask xtream to map it to List implementations but I am not sure xstream guarantees this behavior.

If order is important then my suggestion is to make it **explicitly part of the contract** by adding an order or index attribute to emp element.

Comment: I want ordered based on the occurrence of emp element in xml.

Comment: I cannot make any changes in xml and there is not such attribute by which I can order. It has to be the order of occurrence. Also, I cannot define emps as List in Company class because they have to be unique.