# XStream: problems with Generic LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, xstream, linkedhashmap

I am using XStream 1.4.8 and trying to serialize a generic `LinkedHashMap<?,?>`.

LinkedHashMap does not appear to maintain its order when serialized by XStream. I need to write a new Converter for it so that it does.

The problem is exacerbated by the fact that I have several different types of the Generic class LinkedHashMap in use, and I would like to need only one Converter that works for the generic version.

In other words:
given an a arbitrary Object to serialize that may contain several different kinds of fields of type `LinkedHashMap<?,?>`, how do you marshal and unmarshal them all, with the correct Types used for each of the generics, and with the order maintained in each of the LinkedHashMaps?

This question is similar, but it's not for Generics, and is also based on an older version of XStream:
[Xstream does not maintain order of child elements while unmarshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097017/xstream-does-not-maintain-order-of-child-elements-while-unmarshalling)

Answer (score 0):

You can get some ideas in this source code:

https://github.com/bluesoft-rnd/aperte-workflow-core/blob/master/core/activiti-context/src/main/java/org/aperteworkflow/ext/activiti/ActivitiStepAction.java#L47

```
    Map params = new HashMap();
    if (this.params != null) {
        String xml = (String) this.params.getValue(execution);
        if (xml != null) {
            XStream xs = new XStream();
            xs.alias("map", java.util.Map.class);
            xs.registerConverter(new Converter() {
                public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
                    return AbstractMap.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
                }

                public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
                    AbstractMap<String, String> map = (AbstractMap<String, String>) value;
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                        writer.startNode(entry.getKey().toString());
                        writer.setValue(entry.getValue().toString());
                        writer.endNode();
                    }
                }

                public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    while (reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
                        reader.moveDown();
                        map.put(reader.getNodeName(), reader.getValue());
                        reader.moveUp();
                    }
                    return map;
                }
            });
            params = (Map) xs.fromXML(xml);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works only if the Map is always of type <String, String>. What about the generic case?

Answer (score 0):

Some examples here:

```
/**
 * Checks whether the XStream-based REST converters should be used for
 * rendering the response of this REST request.
 * <p>
 * This method checks whether the request has a query attribute named
 * <tt>"rest"</tt>, or whether there is a system-wide
 * {@link BundleProperties#getProperty(String) bundle/system property}
 * named <tt>"skalli.rest"</tt> with a value <i>different</i> from <tt>"v1"</tt>.
 * In that case, e.g. the request has a query attribute <tt>"rest=v2"</tt>,
 * the method returns <code>false</code> to indicate that the new
 * RestWriter-based converters should be employed. Otherwise the
 * method returns <code>true</code>.
 * <p>
 * If the requested media type is different from <tt>"text/xml"</tt>,
 * always <code>false</code> will be returned.
 *
 * @return <code>true</code>, if XStream-based converters should be used
 * for rendering the response of this REST request.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("nls")
protected boolean enforceOldStyleConverters() {
    if (!context.isXML()) {
        return false;
    }
    String restVersion = getQueryAttribute("rest");
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(restVersion)) {
        restVersion = BundleProperties.getProperty("skalli.rest");
    }
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(restVersion)) {
        return "v1".equalsIgnoreCase(restVersion);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Full source code here:

http://code.openhub.net/file?fid=FMrVl1G9kYhg416Lk5dachOp98c&cid=br-mQGOdySQ&s=XStream%3A%20problems%20with%20Generic%20LinkedHashMap&pp=0&fl=Java&ff=1&filterChecked=true&fp=390342&mp,=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1&projSelected=true#L0

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with either LinkedHashMaps or handling generics. Your link seems to be just the result of typing my question into a search engine and has nothing to do with this either.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I found the solution. For anyone interested, here it is:

It turns out that classes being generic are not actually as much of a problem as I feared. Ironically, Java's compile-time interpretation, which is usually annoying,ends up being to our benefit here: It actually suffices to create a LinkedHashMap with only Object as the generic types.

However, one does need to take care to ensure that the objects stored in the map are unmarshalled as the correct class. This can be done easily enough by just storing the class information for each entry of the map. Note that it does not suffice to store the class information only once for the entire map, since some entries of the map may be subclasses of that class.

```
private static class LinkedHashMapConverter implements Converter {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
        return clazz.equals(LinkedHashMap.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> map = (LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>) value;
        // store each entry
        for (Entry<Object, Object> a : map.entrySet()) {
            writer.startNode("entry");
            // store the key, the value, and the types of both
            writer.startNode("keyClass");
            context.convertAnother(a.getKey().getClass());
            writer.endNode();
            writer.startNode("key");
            context.convertAnother(a.getKey());
            writer.endNode();
            writer.startNode("valueClass");
            context.convertAnother(a.getValue().getClass());
            writer.endNode();
            writer.startNode("value");
            context.convertAnother(a.getValue());
            writer.endNode();
            writer.endNode();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> res = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();
        while (reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
            reader.moveDown();
            // load the key, the value, and the types of both
            reader.moveDown();
            Class keyClass = (Class) context.convertAnother(res, Class.class);
            reader.moveUp();
            reader.moveDown();
            Object key = context.convertAnother(res, keyClass);
            reader.moveUp();
            reader.moveDown();
            Class valueClass = (Class) context.convertAnother(res, Class.class);
            reader.moveUp();
            reader.moveDown();
            Object value = context.convertAnother(res, valueClass);
            reader.moveUp();
            res.put(key, value);
            reader.moveUp();
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```